# Is Python multiple assignment really right-to-left?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

```
x = 1
y = 2

x, y = y, x + y
print(x, y)
```

The above piece prints me: 2, 3

The Python documentation and previous stackoverflow question answers regarding this topic tells that assignment goes from right to left.

So in my case y = x + y goes first -> y = 3, then x = y goes second -> x = 3, and the output should be: 3, 3

If assignment goes from left-to-right, then the resulting output should be: 2, 4

So both left-to-right and right-to-left doesn't work here, seems like it is done simultaneously. My interpreter version is 3.8

Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: The operations are done before assignment I believe, as in right-to-left, assignment is done last.

Comment: There are no "multiple assignments" per-se here. `x + y` is done first, then just a single tuple assignment.

Comment: In *iterable unpacking*, the expression on the right-hand side is fully evaluated *first* (note, you are essentially creating a tuple object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of the assignment is computed all before the assignment happens.

So first you compute `(y, x+y)` which is `(2, 3)` and then you unpack it into `x` and `y`.

See also what happens if on the left you have more than identifiers but also expressions:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> i = 1
>>> a[i], i = 3, 4
>>> a, i
([1, 3], 4)
```